# Problema de iluminación al pasar de escenas en unity

Tags: css, unity, unity3d, game, game-maker

En mi juego tengo varias escenas y cada una se ve bien individualmente, pero cuando paso a la escena del juego desde la escena de menu se cambia la iluminación a como se ve normalmente, se oscureces. Esto también pasa cuando paso del juego a la escena de ganar y con las demás. Ya revise los settings de lightning pero se mantienen iguales al principio.

[image: Iluminación normal de la escena]

[image: Iluminación modificada pasando desde el menu]

Comment: Bienvenida. Es difícil ayudarte si no podemos reproducir el problema y no nos das más información. ¿Si abres el juego directamente en esa escena el problema ocurre? ¿Cómo estás cambiando de escena? Por cierto, quizá quisiste decir C# en lugar de CSS y Game Maker es otro programa que también sirve para hacer juegos.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema y muchos sugieren que eso se arregla solo al compilar el juego. En mi caso, descubrí que se puede solucionar dentro de la ventana de Rendering directamente.

En el menú buscas **Window>Rendering>Lighting>Enviroment** y buscas por la opción de **Enviroment Lighting>Source** y posiblemente tengas seleccionada **Skybox** por defecto, cámbiala por **Color** y listo.